# GAE produces "UnknownError: ApplicationError: 7"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Didn't change code for a month. But today (2012-11-13) started to get strange error "UnknownError: ApplicationError: 7". NOTE: on local GAE function works without errors.

app code from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/gae-python/main.py

```
ApplicationError: 7 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~eventinarea-images/1.362351013166724659/main.py", line 132, in post
    s = json.dumps(self.handle_upload(), separators=(',',':'))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~eventinarea-images/1.362351013166724659/main.py", line 90, in handle_upload
    self.write_blob(fieldStorage.value, result)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~eventinarea-images/1.362351013166724659/main.py", line 74, in write_blob
    files.finalize(blob)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 568, in finalize
    f.close(finalize=True)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 291, in close
    self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Close', request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 427, in _make_rpc_call_with_retry
    _make_call(method, request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 252, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 186, in _raise_app_error
    raise UnknownError(e)
UnknownError: ApplicationError: 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem but it seems to have been fixed silently

Comment: Also happened to me -- seems to be fixed now. Probably an issue on Google's side